# Where can I find the bootanimation.zip in the Evolution X Custom ROM?

Tags: custom-roms, customization, boot-animation

So, I wanted to replace the stock boot animation that comes with Evolution X since it is kind of boring, but the problem was that I couldn't find the `/system/media/` directory in any root browser or even the file manager built within TWRP. I just need to know where I can find the `bootanimation.zip` file in Evolution X, and if there are any further steps required to change it other than just backing up the original boot animation and replacing it.

Specifics: I'm running the latest official build of Evolution X for `zerofltexx` (Samsung Galaxy S6) with MagiskRoot and a few Magisk Modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do a search in the root explorer.you will get the location
System/product/media
Thanks
-redminote5pro
-evolutionx 4.3

Comment: Thanks! I'm guessing I will have to replace `bootanimation-dark.zip` as well as `bootanimation.zip`?